terra::split | R session aborts when splitting polygon fatal error
When trying to split a polygon R runs into a fatal error and aborts. This happens when using R Studio and R on itself. I wrote the code on an earlier version of R on a different machine (also a mac), but have no access to it currently. This happened when I tried to run the code on my current machine. The code is part of a function, which worked fine on the other machine.
I was not able to find a solution. Somewhere it was recommended to reinstall the packages and dependencies and to update R and R Studio to their latest version, which I did. But it did not help.
The raster on which the vector data is based on is only about 60MB, should not be the problem, that it is too large.


library(landscapetools)
library(tidyverse)
library(raster)
library(terra)

raster <- rast("some_raster.tif")
raster <- util_classify(raster, n = 3, level_names = c(1, 2, 3))
polygons <- as.polygons(raster, dissolve = T)
polygon.split <- split(polygons,c(1, 2, 3))

This results in this:
    *** caught segfault ***
    address 0x0, cause 'invalid permissions'
    
    Traceback:
     1: .External(list(name = "CppMethod__invoke_notvoid", address = <pointer: 0x6000024030a0>,     dll = list(name = "Rcpp", path = "/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.4-arm64/Resources/library/Rcpp/libs/Rcpp.so",         dynamicLookup = TRUE, handle = <pointer: 0x2043f2000>,         info = <pointer: 0x600000091380>, forceSymbols = FALSE),     numParameters = -1L), <pointer: 0x60000189d900>, <pointer: 0x6000025e5660>,     .pointer, ...)
     2: x@ptr$split(f)
     3: methods::.hasSlot(x, "ptr")
     4: messages(x@ptr$split(f), "split")
     5: .local(x, f, ...)
     6: split(polygons, c(1, 2, 3))
     7: split(polygons, c(1, 2, 3))
    
    Possible actions:
    1: abort (with core dump, if enabled)
    2: normal R exit
    3: exit R without saving workspace
    4: exit R saving workspace

Here is also the session info:
    > sessionInfo()
    R version 4.4.1 (2024-06-14)
    Platform: aarch64-apple-darwin20
    Running under: macOS Monterey 12.0.1
    
    Matrix products: default
    BLAS:   /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.4-arm64/Resources/lib/libRblas.0.dylib 
    LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.4-arm64/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib;  LAPACK version 3.12.0
    
    locale:
    [1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8
    
    time zone: Europe/Zurich
    tzcode source: internal
    
    attached base packages:
    [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     
    
    other attached packages:
     [1] terra_1.7-78         raster_3.6-26        sp_2.1-4            
     [4] lubridate_1.9.3      forcats_1.0.0        stringr_1.5.1       
     [7] dplyr_1.1.4          purrr_1.0.2          readr_2.1.5         
    [10] tidyr_1.3.1          tibble_3.2.1         ggplot2_3.5.1       
    [13] tidyverse_2.0.0      landscapetools_0.5.0
    
    loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
     [1] gtable_0.3.5     compiler_4.4.1   tidyselect_1.2.1 Rcpp_1.0.12     
     [5] scales_1.3.0     lattice_0.22-6   R6_2.5.1         generics_0.1.3  
     [9] munsell_0.5.1    pillar_1.9.0     tzdb_0.4.0       rlang_1.1.4     
    [13] utf8_1.2.4       stringi_1.8.4    timechange_0.3.0 cli_3.6.3       
    [17] withr_3.0.0      magrittr_2.0.3   grid_4.4.1       hms_1.1.3       
    [21] lifecycle_1.0.4  vctrs_0.6.5      glue_1.7.0       codetools_0.2-20
    [25] fansi_1.0.6      colorspace_2.1-0 tools_4.4.1      pkgconfig_2.0.3 
    > 

As suggested by Chris I wrote a new script using terra only. I try to make it reproducible. split still causes session abort.
library(tidyverse)
library(terra)
library(BAMMtools)
raster <- rast(system.file("ex/elev.tif", package="terra"))
rvals <- values(raster, mat=F, dataframe=F, na.rm=T)
jenks <- getJenksBreaks(rvals, 4)
m <- c(jenks[1], jenks[2],1,
       jenks[2], jenks[3], 2,
       jenks[3], jenks[4], 3)
rclmat <- matrix(m, ncol=3, byrow=TRUE)
rc1 <- classify(raster, rclmat, include.lowest=TRUE)
jenks.poly <- as.polygons(rc1, dissolve = T)
polygon.split <- split(jenks.poly,c(1, 2, 3))

here the error message:
 *** caught segfault ***
address 0x0, cause 'invalid permissions'

Traceback:
 1: .External(list(name = "CppMethod__invoke_notvoid", address = <pointer: 0x600001f056c0>,     dll = list(name = "Rcpp", path = "/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.4-arm64/Resources/library/Rcpp/libs/Rcpp.so",         dynamicLookup = TRUE, handle = <pointer: 0x204d9a520>,         info = <pointer: 0x600003b943c0>, forceSymbols = FALSE),     numParameters = -1L), <pointer: 0x6000023ab600>, <pointer: 0x600001efb000>,     .pointer, ...)
 2: x@ptr$split(f)
 3: methods::.hasSlot(x, "ptr")
 4: messages(x@ptr$split(f), "split")
 5: .local(x, f, ...)
 6: split(jenks.poly, c(1, 2, 3))
 7: split(jenks.poly, c(1, 2, 3))

Possible actions:
1: abort (with core dump, if enabled)
2: normal R exit
3: exit R without saving workspace
4: exit R saving workspace


Development on landscapetools effectively stopped two years ago. With expected results of you previously working, now broken script, in mind, you could likely achieve the same results entirely within terra using either terra::classify or terra::subst. First we'd agree to some data, either your 60mb or <- system.file("ex/elev.tif", package="terra") for example and 'what it should look like'. Welcome again to Stackoverflow.

Without landscapetools and raster I was able to seg fault split, and now fishing back around for how I got there as reprex. But I find split slippery.

I was relying on the landscapetools::util_classify because it calculates the natural breaks using Jenks optimization, which I was after. with terra::classify i will need to do this calculation with a separate command. But I will try. What do you mean with slippery? how can I give you my raster?

Thank you for the suggestions Chris. I adjusted the code, but split still crashes.

Another approach to 'jenks' through classInt discussion. In sp and raster but applicable. Where split seg faults is when it is presented with 'nonsense' as second object, here c(1,2,3) that there is no internal test to guard against such nonsense. Other tests of 2nd object validity length(f) == nlyr(r) are examples of internal guards.

This is clearly a bug (R should never crash), and these are best reported where the software is developed (e.g., github).
In fact, this issue was reported before and fixed in the development version. The github site has instructions to install the development version:
install.packages('terra', repos='https://rspatial.r-universe.dev') 

With that version the example works for me:
library(terra)
#terra 1.7.80

r <- rast(system.file("ex/elev.tif", package="terra"))
rclmat <- matrix(c(141, 306, 403, 306, 403, 547, 1, 2, 3), ncol=3)
rc1 <- classify(r, rclmat, include.lowest=TRUE)
p <- as.polygons(rc1, dissolve = T)

# I would do this
s1 <- split(p, "elevation")
# but you can do
s2 <- split(p, 1:3)

str(s1)
#List of 3
# $ 1:S4 class 'SpatVector' [package "terra"]
# $ 2:S4 class 'SpatVector' [package "terra"]
# $ 3:S4 class 'SpatVector' [package "terra"]


I was in 1.7.78, did read the basic_string::_M_create, but forgot to set my crash report limit, hence no report to compare against #1530. I'll take never crash any day. You might mention for OP benefit how from, to, becomes matrix values were arrived at for 'from, to', and mine.

Thank you both for the your helpful comments. I checked GitHub and installed the development version as written above. My code works now. I learn to check out the Github development page next time. However, I do not see how to arrive at the basic_string::_M_create issue.
